How can I assign a new field of a model in a validator with Pydantic 2?
I am using the 2nd version of Pydantic. I have the following model:
class ScenariosTreeWithUserEscenarioAndDP(ScenariosTreeInDB):
    user_info: Any = Field(None, exclude=True)
    base_scenarios_info: Any = Field(None, exclude=True)
    data_pool_info: Any = Field(None, exclude=True)
    user_name: Optional[str] = None

    @field_validator("user_info", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def gen_user_fields(cls, v, validation_info: ValidationInfo):
        if v:
            validation_info.data["user_name"] = v.name

user_info is an object, and I am testing a case in which information arrives in user_info (therefore the code "validation_info.data["user_name"] = v.name" will be executed). As expected, what I want is to assign the user_name field from user_info. However, under the conditions described above, the field is not assigned and when I print the model, "user_name" is null.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm not sure if validation_info is the actual information that the model will use to validate itself or if it is a copy for reading.
I appreciate the help.
